# Sum rule - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

How do I prove sum rule? $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$ if  $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Note that $A \cup B$ is the union of finite sets.

Comment: There's no way for us to say, unless you tell us what definition of set cardinality you're using, and what results you're allowed to use.

Comment: A non-empty set is finite if for some natural number n exists a bijection between {1,2,...,n} and A. Non-empty set is infinite if it is not finite. The empty set is finite by definition.

Comment: All right, then probably you want to construct a bijection between $A\cup B$ and $\{1,2,\dots,|A|+|B|\}$. Can you think of how to do that, given that you know there are bijections between $A$ and $\{1,\dots,|A|\}$ and between $B$ and $\{1,\dots,|B|\}$?

Comment: I think I can, although I think that there is a more elegant solution. Since there is a bijection f between {1,...m} and A and g between {1,...,n} and B, m=|A|, n=|B|. I would construct a new function h:{1,2,...,m,...,m+n} --> AUB, where h(x)=f(x) for 1<= x <=m and h(x) = g(x) for m< x <=m+n. Now it only remains to prove that the constructed function is a bijection, and it's easy. But since I have not found proof of this theorem in the literature that I have, I thought there might be a more elegant proof.

Comment: Do you have a better idea?

Comment: That's exactly the proof I was thinking of - good job! I don't think there's any more elegant proof, since this fact is just fleshing out stage-one consequences of the definitions.

Comment: @Greg Martin Thanks!